RDKit atom mapping
I have two molecules in RDKit objects (mol_1 ; mol_2):
from rdkit import Chem

mols = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi) for smi in [
    "Nc1ncnc2n(cnc12)[CH]3O[CH](CO[P](O)(O)=O)[CH](O)[CH]3O",
    "CNc1ncnc2n(cnc12)[CH]3O[CH][CH](O)[CH]3O"]
]


mol_1 = mols[0]

mol_2 = mols[1]


that I wish to use to generate an atom-atom mapping. I have tried to leverage the FindMCS  (Find the maximum common substructure of a set of molecules: rdkit.Chem.MCS module) but to me it is unclear  how to get the relationship between atom_i in mol_1 and atom_j in mol_2.
I have tried many things but as a newbie to RDKit. I have gotten lost.
What I want is something like a list of atom indices in mol_1 and the corresponding atom indices in mol_2. It can also be a list of tuples. Say
[(1,2),(2,3)...]
EDITED :
lets start from this code:
import rdkit

print('\n-------------------------------')

print('\n rdkit Version : ', rdkit.__version__)

print('\n-------------------------------')

from rdkit import Chem

from rdkit.Chem.Draw import  MolDraw2DCairo

from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image


import cv2

import numpy as np




mols = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi) for smi in [
    "Nc1ccc(cc1)C-Cc1c(N)cccc1",
    "Nc1ccc(cc1)C=Cc1c(N)cccc1"]
]


mol_1 = mols[0]

mol_1.SetProp("_Name","mol_1")

mol_2 = mols[1]

mol_2.SetProp("_Name","mol_2")



def show_mol(d2d,mol,legend='',highlightAtoms=[]):
    d2d.DrawMolecule(mol,legend=legend, highlightAtoms=highlightAtoms)
    d2d.FinishDrawing()
    bio = BytesIO(d2d.GetDrawingText())
    return Image.open(bio)
def show_images(imgs,buffer=5):
    height = 0
    width = 0
    for img in imgs:
        height = max(height,img.height)
        width += img.width
    width += buffer*(len(imgs)-1)
    res = Image.new("RGBA",(width,height))
    x = 0
    for img in imgs:
        res.paste(img,(x,0))
        x += img.width + buffer
    return res

imgs = []

d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,mol_1,legend = mol_1.GetProp('_Name')))



d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,mol_2,legend = mol_2.GetProp('_Name')))




cv2.namedWindow("Input")
cv2.imshow("Input", cv2.cvtColor(np.array(show_images(imgs)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.waitKey(0)


from rdkit.Chem import rdFMCS


params = rdFMCS.MCSParameters()
params.AtomTyper = rdFMCS.AtomCompare.CompareElements
params.BondTyper = rdFMCS.BondCompare.CompareOrder
params.BondCompareParameters.RingMatchesRingOnly = True
params.BondCompareParameters.CompleteRingsOnly = True

res = rdFMCS.FindMCS(mols, params)


print(res.numAtoms, res.numBonds)


print(type(res))


for i in dir(res):
    
    print(i)
    
    
print('----------')

print(res.numAtoms)
print(res.numBonds)


imgs = []

d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,res.queryMol,legend = 'res'))




cv2.namedWindow("MCS")
cv2.imshow("MCS", cv2.cvtColor(np.array(show_images(imgs)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.waitKey(0)





imgs = []

d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,mol_1,legend = mol_1.GetProp('_Name'), highlightAtoms = mol_1.GetSubstructMatch(res.queryMol) ))



d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,mol_2,legend = mol_2.GetProp('_Name'), highlightAtoms = mol_2.GetSubstructMatch(res.queryMol) ))




cv2.namedWindow("Output")
cv2.imshow("Output", cv2.cvtColor(np.array(show_images(imgs)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.waitKey(0)

that produces:
Input:

MCS :

Output :

Which is the best way to map the MCS atom with the atoms in the two mols (mol_1 , mol_2) ?
I guess that with such an input they 'll be the same.
ANSWER:
It would appear what I am looking for is:
print(mol_1.GetSubstructMatch(res.queryMol))
print(mol_2.GetSubstructMatch(res.queryMol))

https://greglandrum.github.io/rdkit-blog/posts/2023-10-27-mcswhatsnew.html

Any chance to get the two input structures at least ? Their Smiles will be fine. Just to be sure we are playing on the same ground. Thanks

ok so:
import rdkit
print('\n-------------------------------')
print('\n rdkit Version : ', rdkit.__version__)
print('\n-------------------------------')

from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import  MolDraw2DCairo
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np



mols = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi) for smi in [
    "Oc3cc(C1CCCCC1)cc(C2CCCC2)c3",
    "NC4CCC(c3cc(O)cc(C2CCCc1ccccc12)c3)C4"]
]


mol_1 = mols[0]

mol_1.SetProp("_Name","mol_1")

mol_2 = mols[1]

mol_2.SetProp("_Name","mol_2")



def show_mol(d2d,mol,legend='',highlightAtoms=[]):
    d2d.DrawMolecule(mol,legend=legend, highlightAtoms=highlightAtoms)
    d2d.FinishDrawing()
    bio = BytesIO(d2d.GetDrawingText())
    return Image.open(bio)
def show_images(imgs,buffer=5):
    height = 0
    width = 0
    for img in imgs:
        height = max(height,img.height)
        width += img.width
    width += buffer*(len(imgs)-1)
    res = Image.new("RGBA",(width,height))
    x = 0
    for img in imgs:
        res.paste(img,(x,0))
        x += img.width + buffer
    return res

imgs = []

d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,mol_1,legend = mol_1.GetProp('_Name')))



d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,mol_2,legend = mol_2.GetProp('_Name')))




cv2.namedWindow("Input")
cv2.imshow("Input", cv2.cvtColor(np.array(show_images(imgs)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.waitKey(0)


cv2.imwrite('input.png' , cv2.cvtColor(np.array(show_images(imgs)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))


from rdkit.Chem import rdFMCS


params = rdFMCS.MCSParameters()
params.AtomTyper = rdFMCS.AtomCompare.CompareElements
params.BondTyper = rdFMCS.BondCompare.CompareOrder
params.BondCompareParameters.RingMatchesRingOnly = True
params.BondCompareParameters.CompleteRingsOnly = True

res = rdFMCS.FindMCS(mols, params)


imgs = []

d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,res.queryMol,legend = 'res'))


cv2.namedWindow("MCS")
cv2.imshow("MCS", cv2.cvtColor(np.array(show_images(imgs)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('mcs.png' , cv2.cvtColor(np.array(show_images(imgs)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))



imgs = []

d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))


highlightAtoms_mol_1 = mol_1.GetSubstructMatch(res.queryMol)

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,mol_1,legend = mol_1.GetProp('_Name'), highlightAtoms = highlightAtoms_mol_1 ))



d2d = MolDraw2DCairo(350,300)
d2d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True

dopts = d2d.drawOptions()
dopts.setBackgroundColour((0,.9,.9,.3))

highlightAtoms_mol_2 = mol_2.GetSubstructMatch(res.queryMol)

imgs.append(show_mol(d2d,mol_2,legend = mol_2.GetProp('_Name'), highlightAtoms = highlightAtoms_mol_2 ))



cv2.namedWindow("Output")
cv2.imshow("Output", cv2.cvtColor(np.array(show_images(imgs)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('output.png' , cv2.cvtColor(np.array(show_images(imgs)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))


print('\n\n')
print('res.queryMol : ' , res.queryMol)
print('res.queryMol.GetAtoms : ' , [ i.GetIdx() for i in res.queryMol.GetAtoms()])

print('\n\n')
print('highlightAtoms_mol_1 : ' , highlightAtoms_mol_1)

print('\n\n')
print('highlightAtoms_mol_2 : ' , highlightAtoms_mol_2)

print('\n\n')
list_of_tuples = list(zip(highlightAtoms_mol_1 ,highlightAtoms_mol_2)) 
print(list_of_tuples)


gives ;
input:

MCS :

output :

whit printing, last list is the asked :' list of atom indices in mol_1 and the corresponding atom indices in mol_2. It can also be a list of tuples. Say' :
-------------------------------
 rdkit Version :  2024.03.5
-------------------------------


res.queryMol :  <rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol object at 0x7ff4d00ac820>
res.queryMol.GetAtoms :  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

highlightAtoms_mol_1 :  (0, 1, 2, 17, 3, 11, 4, 10, 12, 5, 9, 13, 16, 6, 8, 14, 15, 7)

highlightAtoms_mol_2 :  (8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 11, 21, 4, 12, 20, 3, 22, 13, 15, 2, 1, 14)

[(0, 8), (1, 7), (2, 9), (17, 6), (3, 10), (11, 5), (4, 11), (10, 21), (12, 4), (5, 12), (9, 20), (13, 3), (16, 22), (6, 13), (8, 15), (14, 2), (15, 1), (7, 14)]



